# Navigating Excel Document when Form is Active

Tags: excel, forms, vba

ANSWER: Change the Userform property "ShowModal" to false.

Found answer here.
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/383493-allow-application-scrolling-behind-userform.html

---

The form disables navigation to the excel document. I cannot scroll, click, or move around at all. I made buttons to do this for me but that's pretty lame. I've googled this but I'm obviously not using the right terms.

What can I do to enable navigation to the document while the form is visible and active?

Comment: Change the `Modality` of the form.

Comment: Yep! I found the answer, came here to tell the masses I'm a fool, and I saw your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Try setting the Userform property 'ShowModal' to false. That will allow you to interact with the sheet while keeping the userform visible."

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/383493-allow-application-scrolling-behind-userform.html

There it is...just tried different googling.